# How to push tag to specific branch in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a branch called `v2.0` in gerrit. Now I want to the current stat of this branch as `v2.0.1`.

In my local repository I checked out the branch, then added the tag using

```
git tag v2.0.1
```

Now I'm trying to push that to gerrit, but I'm not sure how. I tried this:

```
$ git push origin v2.0.1 HEAD:refs/heads/v2.0
! [remote rejected] v2.0.1 -> v2.0 (prohibited by Gerrit)
```

How can I push the tag to gerrit?

Answer (score 25):

After some googling, I found the answer:

`gerrit` accepts only annotated tags. It's quite straightforward to create and push an annotated tag:

```
git checkout v2.0
git tag -am "Adding v2.0.1 tag" v2.0.1
git push origin v2.0.1 HEAD:refs/heads/v2.0
```

Comment: The above command works for me, I was just hoping that someone could explain the push. Why is the tag pushed to refs/heads/branchname and not refs/tags?

Comment: HEAD:refs/heads/v2.0 is unneeded. It is an additional refspec that pushes HEAD on the local repository to refs/heads/v2.0 on gerrit. 
The "v2.0.1" is what pushes the tag to gerrit, it is equivalent to refs/tags/v2.0.1:refs/tags/v2.0.1

Comment: As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194475/2285820) answer, Gerrit also supports leightweight tags using the `Create Reference` permission on `refs/tags/*`

Answer (score 13):

1. Add the permissions:

Click your project `Access`, add permissions as following:

```
Reference:  
refs/tags/*

Push Annotated Tag 
Push Signed Tag
```

2. Add your tags

Annotated tag: `git tag -a "message" tag_name`

Signed tag: `git tag -s tag_name`

3. push your tags

simple cmd: `git push --tags`

If you want to fetch tags from your server repo using cmd:

`git fetch --tags`

You can check the doc:

https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_annotated
https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_signed

Answer (score 6):

Tags and branches are completely independent concepts in Git, so your command doesn't make sense. A tag only links to a commit, and is repository-wide.

Both tags and branches are references, think about tags as fixed references to a commit, and branches as moving references on the tip of a commits' branch.

If the commit tagged `v2.0.1` is already in the `v2.0` branch I'd say you only have to push both to `origin`. If not, you'll want to merge the branch containing the tag into the `v2.0` branch, and push both.

Answer (score 1):

If you push a lightweight tag, you should add the privilege 'Create Reference' for the reference name `refs/tags/*`, because as CharlesB said, both tags and branches are references.

After adding the 'Create Reference' right, you can use `git push --tags` to push lightweight tags.